# glGenerateMipmap crashes on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, opengles

I'm testing a C++ program made with GLFW and it crashes with a segmentation fault on Pi 3 but not on Pi 4.

The reason of the crash is the call to glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D).

Systems tested:

- Raspberry Pi OS 64bit and 32bit / Mesa 19.3.2
- sakaki's gentoo64 / Mesa 20.1.1

Is that a known issue?

Meanwhile, I found a workaround: using gluBuild2DMipmaps() together with

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```